# How to get the Route object from an URI?

Tags: 8, routes, uri

If I have a `Url` object, or even a simple string representation of path such as `/node/2`, how can I get the full `Route` object?

Answer (score 12):

You can retrieve this information from the Symfony router. This can be accessed in Drupal through the `router.no_access_checks` service.

If you have a simple path (note that the path has a leading slash):

```
$router = \Drupal::service('router.no_access_checks');
$result = $router->match('/node/2');
```

If you have a `Url` object:

```
$router = \Drupal::service('router.no_access_checks');
$result = $router->match($url->toString());
```

This will return an array that includes the route object, as well as other useful information such as the route name and route parameters, the controller, the title callback and even the entity object represented by the URL.