# Is it possible to generate an URL object from a path?

Tags: 8

Can I generate a

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Url.php/class/Url/8.2.x

from a simple path, e.g. "/products/widget" ?

(assume /products/widget exists in the system and is a canonical path)

Answer (score 1):

Use Url:fromRoute () and pass in the route's name and arguments. You can also use fromUri() for external paths. https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Url.php/function/Url%3A%3AfromRoute/8.2.x

I usually find the route name by searching the routing.yml files for the path.

Alternately, you can do this. [How to get the Route object from an URI?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/218180/how-to-get-the-route-object-from-an-uri)